# How to make ImageButtons bounds wrap around the image?

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I'm making a GUI for an android app, this GUI contains a four direction `ImageButtons` (look at the following image):

[image]

but when trying to make that always fails because a square reserved for each image, and that's what i reached :

[image]

and that's my **XML code** :

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/circle"
   android:layout_weight="4"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

               <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/up"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:scaleType="centerInside"
                 android:src="@drawable/remote_button_up"/>

         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

              <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/remote_button_left"/>

              <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/remote_button_right"/>

         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical">

              <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/down"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/remote_button_down"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you upload one picture and give us a link?

Comment: You have to draw it using canvas. Or you can use only the arrow as imagebutton and other round shape will remain as background.

Comment: Take one ImageView for this and take the onTouchListener, the calculate the position and the wanted arrow.

Comment: @Nidzaaaa http://s6.postimg.org/eouo9yk8d/remote_button_up.png

Comment: @Andru sorry don't get your point

Comment: @A.S. but that will be ineffective while using different screen sizes, i mean how will i know the position if i have like 5 screens

Comment: calculate it procentual from the imagesize, eg y <= 0.3 * ImageHeight  and 0.3 * ImageWidth < x < 0.6 * ImageWidth (upper arrow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a work around for that..You can achieve it like this...[image]

Here you create a bigger layout (in red) and put whole image at once...Now create few more layouts (in yellow) and  dont put any backgrounds on them .now set onclicklisteners on these layouts...by this way you can achieve it to some extent...hope you got me...