# How to create button of desired shape in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

I am trying to create 4 buttons as shown on the image below. Each button is clickable.
How can I go about this.

[image]

Comment: look at documentation of shape drawable

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight way to achieve this. However you can achieve this by doing some workaround and help of layouts. You can check one of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633304/how-to-make-imagebuttons-bounds-wrap-around-the-image/20633809#20633809) with similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can take ImageButton widget of Android.

And u can set any Image in background using **background:src**.

That is done what you want.

Comment: doing this way I would get only rectangular buttons not in the shape I desired

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Button class and write your own customized button.
This may help http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html