# Triangular shaped button for android activity

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-imagebutton

In my android application activity, I need to arrange 6 buttons as shown below: 
The buttons are named from 1 to 6. When I try to add each button as background to the buttons, there is a problem that the buttons are overlapping each other. The background png image of the button are triangular in shape. When I add these background png to the buttons, its background image changes, but the borders of the button are still rectangle in shape. So I need the buttons with triangular borders, so that I can place them in a format like the below screenshot. Also I don't which layout suits most for this type pattern. So please do suggest that also..

[image]

Comment: Did you try the layer-list to draw triangle shape

Comment: no... I didn't know how to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for triangle shape: call it as a background for your textview or any.

triangle.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
      <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-40%"
        android:pivotY="100%"
        >
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">

              <corners android:radius="15dip" />
              <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
           </shape>
      </rotate>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

//TEXTVIEW CALLING

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="@dimen/triangle"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/triangle"
  android:rotation="90"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:background="@drawable/triangle"/>
```

Comment: you mean that I have to place inside this in my drawable folder??

Comment: I have a background image for each 6 triangles. For demo, I have created it using paint and used the same color in all of them..

Comment: yes.save it as a new drawable resource file. and paste my code there.

Comment: @TeeJay create a triangle.xml file in drawable folder then use it in layout file as shown in code

Comment: @sherin android:layout_width="@dimen/triangle" is showing an error

Comment: @sherin okay, and how to handle clicks on each button?

Comment: @vokilam : I hope you will add the triangle.xml as a background for any View that which mention in answer.For textview you can make a click function

Comment: I have to give click for all the view, someone has any idea?

Comment: @SagarPanwala :I am not sure . Try this .. Give different id to the TextView and call that "Id " for the click function .

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer of mine, i think you can follow this approach to achieve your goal..
[[How to make ImageButtons bounds wrap around the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633304/how-to-make-imagebuttons-bounds-wrap-around-the-image/20633809#20633809][1])