# Android : Image Button without back background

Tags: android, xml

I'm developing an Android application based on the Simon Game ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game) ). To represent the buttons of the game (blue, red yellow and green) I drew buttons  that I will use in a ImageButton.

[Exempl of a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT0e7.png)

As  you can see, my buttons have a special shape, and the images have **no background**. I would like that the clickable area matches the shape of the button but it doesn't. It matches a square around my image.

So, my question is, do you know how can i define the clickable area so it matches only the "triangular" shape of my button ?

I already tested this :

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/btnj"
android:id="@+id/btnImgJaune"
android:background="@null"
android:clickable="false" />`
```

Thank you.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396194/creating-a-triangular-shaped-button-for-android-application   or this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398788/triangular-shaped-button-for-android-activity maybe can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can creat custom click able shape on a image in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499282/how-can-creat-custom-click-able-shape-on-a-image-in-android)

Comment: Thx for your answer. I already checked those topics but my buttons are not perfect triangles, they have a  rounded exterior and I don't know how to use the xml proprieties to do that.

Comment: There is an image of my triangle in my post

Answer (score 0):

An Android `View` has a square shape, so you can't do that. Maybe you can try implementing your own [ViewOutlineProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider.html) with a `radius` [Outline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html).

Comment: Thanks you. I'll check for that.